# Create custom theme for module

Tags: theming, 8

I've creating an intranet module for Drupal 8 and I want to use a custom theme for it, like an admin theme(with page/node/field templates) where I can map region like menu, header, footer... but only for my module.

I didn't find any specific doc about this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would require creating a theme (in addition to your module).  Then have your module indicate it uses that theme.  Here is a nice article on how to do this https://speedandfunction.com/switching-themes-programmatically-drupal-8/

In this scenario, you would have your main theme and the theme used by your module.  You could indicate that the theme used by your module was a sub-theme (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme) of your main theme which could reduce some theme coding management.

Comment: I found an article like yours for my needs here : http://annakalata.com/blog/drupal-8-how-switch-theme-based-pages-active-menu I just replace the active menu by my route name. I think I explain it much better.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify region on your module, but you can custom your page or your block.

Regions are specify into main theme.

First, you need to create a folder on your module root directory :

> myModule/templates

Inside, you ll put all your custom template.

For example :

> page1.html.twig
>
> page2.html.twig

Then you need to declare all your templates :

> In myModule.module :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function myModule_theme() {
  return [
    'page1' => [
      'template' => 'test',
      'variables'=>array('test'=>NULL),
      'render element' => 'children',
    ],

      'page2' => [
          'template' => 'page2',       
          'render element' => 'form',
      ],
  
  ];
}
```

And after, in your controller or your form :

```
return $build +  [
  '#theme'=>'page1',
  '#test'=>"its content for my variable inside my template",
];
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, but that's what I do for now and I don't like this way, that make no sense to include every part of the module ( header, footer, menu, aside) on every page it should be the opposite. I hope someone could find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If u want custom theme for module u just need to use template suggestions, output content from php and then render it in twig files.